# React and PokéAPI: Mapping through multiple arrays of objects to get Pokémon info only gives me info of only one Pokémon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I'm working on a personal project to practice React, which is a Pokédex application.

I'm using both React and the PokéAPI here. I'll show the code snippet at the bottom of this question.

I had to do two API calls because the first one was about getting the name of the Pokémon and the second was to retrieve more information (which needed the name of the Pokémon).

The challenge is, I was getting back objects of information about each Pokémon, and I needed arrays so I could map through what I needed within the JSX render. Hence, I used the Object.values method, which inevitably lead me to having an array of objects I could iterate through, which is great!

However, now when I map through all the objects I want, I am only getting the most recent Pokémon render (i.e. let's say I want to see information about 151 Pokémon, I'll only be able to see Mew and "151" on the screen [this is me asking for name and ID].)

In the code snippet below, I just changed the limit to 9 Pokémon so that way I don't need to load to much data to see if my code is working:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PokemonCard from './PokemonCard';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pokemonInfo:[],
      result: [],
      pokemonName: "",
      pokemonID: [],
      introRegion: "",
      primaryType: "",
      secondaryType: "",
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

      axios({
        method:'GET',
        url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=9`,
        dataResponse: 'json',
      })
        .then((dataOne) => {
          console.log(dataOne.data.results)

          this.setState({
            result: dataOne.data.results
          })

          this.state.result.map(async(fetchInfo) => {
            return axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: `${fetchInfo.url}`,
                dataResponse: 'json',
              })
              .then( (dataTwo) =>{
                const dataTwoArray = Object.values(dataTwo)
                console.log(dataTwoArray)

                this.setState({
                  pokemonInfo: [dataTwoArray]
                })
              });
          })
        });
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">

            <h1>Pokédex!</h1>

            {this.state.pokemonInfo.map((getInfo) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <h3>{getInfo[0].id}</h3>

                  <h3>{getInfo[0].name}</h3>

                </>
              )
            })}
            {/* <PokemonCard /> */}


            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I would like to see all the names and IDs of al the Pokémon I've been asking for.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: this.setState() is an asynchronous operation. You shouldn't rely on `this.state` to be populated right after `this.setState()`. Instead, maybe loop through `dataOne.data` (but there might be other problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a several issues with your attempt here. Some of them related to your question, others not so much.

To get down to those related to your problem: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what `setState` does. The function `setState` takes a partial version of the new state and creates the next state -- this then re-renders the component once the state has been updated. The key is that it's a partial view of the state, not a modification of the existing state. Why that's relevant I'll detail in point #2.

1) First off, you call `setState` to update `result` to the API Response, then you immediately follow that up trying to use `this.state.result` -- this may work, but it's very problematic. You're not supposed to depend on *when* `setState` has updated `this.state`. Typically you already have the data you passed on anyways so just use that. In this case, instead of mapping `this.state.result` you should be mapping `dataOne.data.results`. It's possible that this use of `this.state` after `setState` works but it's a race condition nightmare waiting to happen and very bad practice. Break it now.

2) Secondly, and to my earlier point. `setState` is taking a partial view of the next state. So when you call `this.setState({ pokemonInfo: [dataTwoArray] })` you're not saying "add this new value to the array in `pokemonInfo`" you are saying `"replace the current list of information with this new list of information"`. I don't much like recommending this, because it falls back to the issue with the first part, but you can solve this by spreading the existing array and/or concating the new one. `this.setState({ pokemonInfo: this.state.pokemon.concat([dataTwoArray]) })` or (more modern) `this.setState({ pokemonInfo: [...this.state.pokemonInfo, dataTwoArray] })`. Both of these depend on previous calls to `setState` succeed in order for all existing values to have been captured accordingly, which is problematic.

Okay, so **the issue** is that when you update the pokemonInfo, you set it to only a single value in an array. In doing so you only (typically) see the final one that came through (more accurately, the last one to complete a request).

Now, I said my solutions to problem 2 were bad, and they are. Since you're really building a list of promises and you want to wait for them all to complete, you should do that with more promises.

```
// inside the first promise's then

// We start by starting a request promise by mapping each pokemon
// data to a request. This results in pokePromises being an array
// of Promise objects.
const pokePromises = dataOne.data.results.map(pokemon => axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: pokemon.url, // notice no need here to make it a string, it's already a string!
  dataResponse: 'json',
}));

// Now wait for all the requests to finish before doing more, Promise.all
// creates a promise that will resolve when all given promises have been
// resolved. This doesn't handle errors though, we're assuming all success
// here.
Promise.all(pokePromises).then(allPokeData => {
  // This takes each response object and converts into a an array 
  // of values, just like you do already. We're just operating on
  // all the results at one time instead of one result like you are.
  const pokemonInfo = allPokeData.map(data => Object.values(data));

  // Now that we have all the data we set the state, but we use
  // an ES6 shorthand that expands to `{ pokemonInfo: pokemonInfo }`
  this.setState({ pokemonInfo });
});
```

(CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-edison-kfp85)

Another option, that might reduce the amount of change you make is to pass an update function to `setState` instead of an object.

That would require your final update to `pokemonInfo` to look something like this:

```
// This way of updating state guarantees we get the current version 
// of state (in the updater function) when this update is being
// applied and can ensure us that our new pokemonInfo will truly contain
// the previous and new values as expected.
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state, // merge in previous state
  pokemonInfo: [...state.pokemonInfo, dataTwoArray],
}));
```

(CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-noether-5z53f)

The other issues that you have with your code are names. Like `dataOne`, `dataTwo`, and `dataTwoArray` have no meaning in the context of reading your code. They might make some sense to you now, but they won't in a month or more when you come back and look at this project. Nor do they mean anything to anyone else reading your code. You should strive to use meaningful and readable names. So `dataOne` should be `pokeListResponse`, and perhaps `dataTwo` should be `pokeData` or `pokemonResponse`, `fetchInfo` is a Pokémon, so call it `pokemon`, right? Also pay attention to your data types. `fetchInfo.url` is a string, interpolating into a string is pointless and redundant. Work on your indentation and spacing too. It could be the format of StackOverflow, or whatever editor your using but it's all over the place. Spacing is a good thing, it adds order and cleanliness to the code. Very necessary for readability.

Anywho, hope you found some and/or all of this helpful. Work on understanding how the React component lifecycle works and how updating state ties into re-renders -- as well as a deeper understanding of JS. At least judging by this code example it seems you have some surface knowledge. Keep growing, and expanding your wealth of knowledge!

Comment: Brandon, your comment truly helped me with my work, and for that I thank you.
I realize that I need to learn more about states and lifecycles in react, as they can get a little jumbled up and confusing. It will take some practice and that's exactly why I'm building this with React, practice makes perfect.
Thanks for also telling me about some best practices such as not using a state the second you update it, etc...
However, I do have one question. Why did we use Promise.all instead of a .then().catch() method? I'm still trying to learn, so anything you have to say would help! Cheers :)

Comment: @sizreem I used `Promise.all` because `axios` returns a promise that resolves/rejects when the request completes. Since updating an array in state needs it's current value, I figured it'd be better to wait until all the requests for each individual pokémon completed -- so I created the requests and used `Promise.all` which resolves when all the pokémon requests have completed. Alternatively the second approach uses an alternative implementation of `setState` that takes an update function that is guaranteed to get the latest state so there was no need for `Promise.all` -- hope that helps.